# Angular *ngIf async as variable with multiple condition on same level not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to refactor my code

```
<ng-container *ngIf='taskOutputs$ | async as taskOutputs && taskOutputs.outputs.length; else neverImportedOrLoading'>
```

I'm getting `Unexpected token &&, expected identifier`

Should I absolutely split this in a child `ng-container` HTML item ? like bellow ?

```
<ng-container *ngIf='taskOutputs$ | async as taskOutputs && taskOutputs.outputs.length; else neverImportedOrLoading'>
  <ng-container taskOutputs.outputs.length; else neverImportedOrLoading'>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

**Edit**

Doing it this way (adding `()` )

```
<ng-container *ngIf='(taskOutputs$ | async as taskOutputs) && taskOutputs.outputs.length; else neverImportedOrLoading'>
```

got another error:

```
Missing expected ) at column 23 in [(taskOutputs$ | async as taskOutputs) && taskOutputs.outputs.length; else neverImportedOrLoading]
```

Comment: Try `(taskOutputs$ | async as taskOutputs)`

Comment: I get `Missing expected ) at column 23 in [(taskOutputs$ | async as taskOutputs) && taskOutputs.outputs.length; else neverImportedOrLoading]`

Answer (score 2):

I suggested use two ng-container

```
<ng-container *ngIf='{tasks:taskOutputs$ | async} as data'>
   <ng-container *ngIf="data.tasks && data.tasks.length else neverImportedOrLoading">
        ...see that you need use data.tasks.., e.g.
        <div *ngFor="let task of data.tasks">
             {{task.taskId}}
        </div>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

See that the first condition `{task:taskOutputs$|async}` it's always fulfilled